# ExtJS DataStore with Sub-Array: Not loading Data correctly

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am implementing a little grid editor for some data which has some meta-data, and then an associated array inside it with several data points that will be used later for graphing etc.

Now the problem I'm having is to actually load up this data successfully into the datastore, I've been going through as much docs as I can, but it's hard to find exactly what I'm looking for as I am new to using ExtJS so my search terminology might be incorrect. So how exactly should I be structuring my ExtJS Data Model to load the data as I currently have it structured ?

If anyone can point me to the correct documentation, or a working example so I can see what I'm doing incorrectly that would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have written so far:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.Panel',
    'Ext.layout.container.Column'
]);

Ext.define('TargetProfile', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields  : ['profileName', 'description', 'metaData'],
    hasMany : {model: 'TargetPoint', name: 'value'}
});

Ext.define('TargetPoint', {
    extend      : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields      : [
        {name: 'startTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'H:i'},
        {name: 'endTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'H:i'},
        {name: 'targetValue', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'comments'}
    ],
    belongsTo   : 'TargetProfile'
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '/images/s.gif';
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var bd = Ext.getBody();

    var tData = ['TestProfile1', 'Testing', 'Just another test',
        [
        [1, '00:00', '04:00', 27, 'Start of day'],
        [2, '04:00', '08:00', 70, 'Ramp up'],
        [3, '08:00', '13:00', 55, 'Mid day period'],
        [4, '13:00', '18:00', 38, 'Finishing production'],
        [5, '18:00', '20:00', 25, 'Shutting down'],
        [6, '20:00', '00:00', 20, 'Overnight period']
        ]
    ];

    var tDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        model   : 'TargetProfile',
        fields  : ['profileName', 'description', 'metaData',
            [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'startTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'H:i'},
            {name: 'endTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'H:i'},
            {name: 'targetValue', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'comments'}
            ]
        ],
        data    : tData
    });

    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToMoveEditor  : 2,
        autoCancel          : false,
        clicksToEdit        : 2,
        pluginId            : 'rowEditing'
    });

    rowEditing.on('canceledit', function(me) {
        tDataStore.load();
    });

    var gridForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        id              : 'targetForm',
        frame           : true,
        title           : 'Target Profile',
        bodyPadding     : 5,
        width           : 750,
        layout          : 'column',
        fieldDefaults   : {
            labelAlign  : 'left',
            msgTarget   : 'side'
        },
        dockedItems : [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            width: 750,
            dock: 'top',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Add Target Point',
                iconCls: 'icon-add',
                handler: function() {
                    rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                    var r = Ext.create('TargetPoint', {
                        startTime   : '00:00',
                        endTime     : '00:00',
                        targetValue : 0,
                        comments    : ''
                    });
                    tDataStore.insert(0, r);
                    rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Save Profile',
                iconCls: 'icon-save',
                handler: function() {
                    tDataStore.save()
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Delete Profile',
                iconCls: 'icon-delete',
                handler: function() {
                    var selection = gridForm.child('gridpanel').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                    if (selection) {
                        tDataStore.remove(selection);
                    }
                }
            }]
        }],
        items           : [{
            columnWidth : 0.60,
            xtype       : 'gridpanel',
            store       : tDataStore,
            plugins      : [rowEditing],
            height      : 400,
            title       : 'Target Data',
            columns     : [{
                text        : 'Start Time',
                width       : 75,
                sortable    : true,
                dataIndex   : 'startTime',
                renderer    : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i'),
                editor      : new Ext.form.TimeField({format: 'H:i'})
            }, {
                text        : 'End Time',
                width       : 75,
                sortable    : true,
                dataIndex   : 'endTime',
                renderer    : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i'),
                editor      : new Ext.form.TimeField({format: 'H:i'})
            }, {
                text        : 'Target Value',
                width        : 75,
                sortable    : true,
                dataIndex   : 'targetValue',
                editor      : new Ext.form.NumberField()
            }, {
                text        : 'Comments',
                flex        : 1,
                sortable    : false,
                dataIndex   : 'comments',
                editor      : new Ext.form.TextField()
            }],
            listeners   : {
                selectionchange: function(model, records) {
                    if (records[0]) {
                        this.up('form').getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            columnWidth : 0.4,
            margin      : '0 0 0 10',
            xtype       : 'fieldset',
            title       : 'Target Point Details',
            defaults    : {
                width       : 240,
                labelWidth  : 90
            },
            defaultType : 'textfield',
            items       : [{
                fieldLabel  : 'Start Time',
                name        : 'startTime',
                format      : 'H:i',
                xtype       : 'timefield'
            }, {
                fieldLabel  : 'End Time',
                name        : 'endTime',
                xtype       : 'timefield',
                format      : 'H:i'
            }, {
                fieldLabel  : 'Target Value',
                name        : 'targetValue'
            }, {
                fieldLabel  : 'Comments',
                name        : 'comments'
            }]
        }, {
            columnWidth : 0.4,
            margin      : '0 0 0 10',
            xtype       : 'fieldset',
            title       : 'Meta Data',
            store       : tDataStore,
            defaults    : {
                width       : 240,
                labelWidth  : 90
            },
            defaultType : 'textfield',
            items       : [{
                fieldLabel  : 'Profile Name',
                name        : 'profileName'
            }, {
                fieldLabel  : 'Description',
                name        : 'description'
            }, {
                fieldLabel  : 'Meta-data',
                name        : 'metaData',
                xtype       : 'textarea',
                rows        : 11
            }]
        }],
        renderTo    : bd
    });

    gridForm.child('gridpanel').getSelectionModel().select(0);
});
```

And an image of what it looks like when rendered out:

[image: Current Rendering]

Now if I revert the changes on my DataStores to this

```
var myData = [
    [1, '00:00', '04:00', 27, 'Start of day'],
    [2, '04:00', '08:00', 70, 'Ramp up'],
    [3, '08:00', '13:00', 55, 'Mid day period'],
    [4, '13:00', '18:00', 38, 'Finishing production'],
    [5, '18:00', '20:00', 25, 'Shutting down'],
    [6, '20:00', '00:00', 20, 'Overnight period']
];

var myMetaData = [
    ['TestProfile1',
     'Testing',
     'Testing the\ntextarea\nbox'
    ]
];

var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields  : [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'startTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'H:i'},
        {name: 'endTime', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'H:i'},
        {name: 'targetValue', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'comments'}
    ],
    data    : myData
});

var ms = Ext.create('Ext.data.SimpleStore', {
    fields  : ['profileName', 'description', 'metaData'],
    data    : myMetaData
});
```

I get the following which is more what I was aiming for (although now it's loading the second datastore which contains my meta-data hence the change to wanting to use 1 store which contains everything, as well as that's the MongoDB Data Model for it)

[image: Previous Rendering]

Comment: You are defining `tDataStore` as having certain fields, but also define a model for it (`TargetProfile`) which has different fields. The docs say you shouldn't define fields in the store, but only in the model. I guess you'll have to ask more questions here for me to better be able to help you.

Comment: Please revise and boil your code down to a simple test case of the problem area.  This is basically a dump of your whole app.

Answer (score 0):

In your `hasMany` association, the value of `name` property represents the variable in the data where Ext is supposed to read an Array of related models. From the documentation, you have this example of models :

```
Ext.define('Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',      type: 'int'},
        {name: 'user_id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name',    type: 'string'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',   type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ],
    // we can use the hasMany shortcut on the model to create a hasMany association
    hasMany: {model: 'Product', name: 'products'}
});
```

Ext will then expect the User store's data with the following format :

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "User 1",
        "products" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "user_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Product 1"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "user_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Product 2"
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "user_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Product 3"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

So, you only need to load one of the stores with the correct data and their related subdata, and it will automatically make the connections, and you can directly access the User's Products with `user.products()` (which will return a Store containing the subdata for **this** record)